# ttyUSB writing the received data back

Tags: c, serial-port, linux-device-driver, tty

I have CP2108 device connected to my hardware, it has 4 interfaces: /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1, /dev/ttyUSB2, /dev/ttyUSB3

I connected /dev/ttyUSB0 to /dev/ttyUSB1

We have also set the baud rate properly to 9600 using stty command

I am transmitting hello from `echo "hello" > /dev/ttyUSB0`

I receive "hello" back in /dev/ttyUSB1 and /dev/ttyUSB0

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0

cat /dev/ttyUSB1
```

Looking at the driver logs, after read_callback on USB1 it also calls write_callback , why is this happening, as the expected behavior is to only receive on USB1

Thanks for your patience and time

Update:

```
stty -a -F /dev/ttyUSB1
speed 600 baud;stty: /dev/ttyUSB1
 line = 216;
intr = f; quit = ^B; erase = M-'; kill = 8; eof = <undef>; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = ^?; start = s;
stop = @; susp = <undef>; rprnt = <undef>; werase = <undef>; lnext = ^C; flush = <undef>; min = 0; time = 0;
-parenb parodd cs5 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip inlcr -igncr icrnl -ixon -ixoff iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
-opost olcuc ocrnl onlcr onocr onlret ofill ofdel nl1 cr3 tab3 bs1 vt1 ff0
-isig icanon -iexten echo echoe echok echonl noflsh xcase tostop echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Comment: You need to analyze the termios settings of the receiving serial terminal, i.e. `stty -a -F /dev/ttyUSB1`, to see if echoing is enabled.  It probably is, since it's commonly employed for normal canonical terminal communications.

Comment: Vote to close: this isn't a programming question.

Comment: I added stty command output. Can you please look

Comment: its because you have echo enable. try `stty -echo /dev/ttyUSB1` this will solve echo issue. credit goes to sawdust who asked for these stty logs. hope this solves the issue.

Comment: After disabling all the -echo it solved the problem. Thanks sawdust, Devidas